# Inline-block position not as expected (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css

for a bit of fun I decided to make a sliding shelf today. I got it looking and working how I wanted and then decided to put some content in the cards.

I added text to the first card and it moved down almost on to a new line. I can't explain why this happened (though I'm sure there's a simple explanation). Can one of you tell me what I'm missing, please?

Thank you

```js
function hideTrigger() {
  leftTrig.removeAttribute("hidden");
  rightTrig.removeAttribute("hidden");
  switch (pos) {
    case 0:
      leftTrig.setAttribute("hidden", "");
      break;
    case posMax:
      rightTrig.setAttribute("hidden", "")
  }
}

function moveHelper() {
  boxesCont.style.transform = slideHelper(), hideTrigger(), setTimeout(function() {
    end = boxCont[posMax].getBoundingClientRect().left <= window.innerWidth ? 1 : 0
  }, 300)
}

function slideHelper() {
  return "translate(-" + boxSize * pos + "px)"
}

function moveRight() {
  pos < posMax && (end ? endHelper() : (pos++, moveHelper()))
}

function moveLeft() {
  pos > 0 && (pos--, moveHelper())
}

function moveTo(e) {
  e >= 0 && e <= posMax && (pos = e, moveHelper())
}

function endHelper() {
  pos++;
  let edgeDif = boxSize - boxMargin - (window.innerWidth - boxCont[posMax].getBoundingClientRect().left);
  rightTrig.setAttribute("hidden", ""), boxesCont.style.transform = "translate(-" + (boxSize * (pos - 1) + edgeDif) + "px)"
}

var leftTrig = document.querySelector(".directional.left");
var rightTrig = document.querySelector(".directional.right");
var boxesCont = document.querySelector(".shelf .boxes");
var boxCont = boxesCont.querySelectorAll(".box");
var boxStyle = boxCont[0].currentStyle || window.getComputedStyle(boxCont[0]);
var boxMargin = parseFloat(boxStyle.marginLeft);
var boxSize = boxCont[0].offsetWidth + 2 * boxMargin;
var end = 0;
var pos = 0;
var posMax = boxCont.length - 1;

leftTrig.addEventListener("click", function() {
  moveLeft()
});
rightTrig.addEventListener("click", function() {
  moveRight()
});

moveHelper();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Roboto;
  text-align: justify;
}

.shelf {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
}

.shelf button.directional {
  position: absolute;
  transition: opacity 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  height: 100%;
  width: 30px;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: rgba(55, 71, 79, 0.4);
  color: #F5F5F5;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.shelf button.directional.left {
  left: 0;
}

.shelf button.directional.right {
  right: 0;
}

.boxes {
  white-space: nowrap;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
}

.box {
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 2px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  font-size: 16px;
}

.box:nth-child(even) {
  background: #f44336;
}

.box:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #2196F3;
}

.shelf:hover button.directional {
  opacity: 1;
}

.shelf:hover button.directional:hover {
  background: rgba(55, 71, 79, 0.8);
}

*[hidden] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="shelf">
  <button class="directional left">&lsaquo;</button>
  <div class="boxes">
    <div class="box">test</div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <button class="directional right">&rsaquo;</button>
</div>
```

Link to [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/7m6ej0m9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to your `.box`.

This will get your inline block elements to align themselves vertically across their top points.

Comment: So the baseline with .box elements with content was the bottom of the content and the baseline .box elements without content was the bottom of the whole element?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes. I'm not 100% sure how it all works though but you are usually best setting a value for the `vertical-align` property when using `inline-block`, just to avoid any unexpected layout issues.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with inline-block elementsis, most browsers including IE will add 1px around inline and inline-block elements.

> https://davidwalsh.name/remove-whitespace-inline-block
>
> https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/
>
> https://matthewlein.com/articles/inline-block-no-space-font/
>
> https://tylercipriani.com/blog/2012/08/01/display-inline-block-extra-margin/

This happens if you stack your inline-block elements. Meaning, in order to keep your code more readible if you put line breaks in html before inline-block elements, you will get this gap and it will cause unwanted UI.

So basically you need to set font-size:0 to wrapper element then set your font-size back to normal in inline-block elements if you have to keep them in separate lines like

```
<li>Some content<li>
<li>Some content<li>
<li>Some content<li>
```

or you need to merge them in single line

```
<li>Some content<li><li>Some content<li><li>Some content<li>
```

Comment: My container already has font-size:0, this question was about alignment as opposed to white space. Thanks though 

Comment: Yeah, I had similar issue with menu items before and no matter what I did one menu item on horizontal plane was mis-aligning, then found out that freaking 1px white-space was pushing last element.